# Twitch player buffer size increase

Tags: google-chrome, video, streaming, video-streaming

When watching videos on twitch, you can (on PC) bring up the video statistics

[image: twitch player video statistics]

The screen shot shows a buffer of 27s (at 2829kbps).  This value stays pretty constant which would indicate that the buffer size is roughly 76mb for me at least.

I was wondering whether buffer size was in any way configurable (either through the player settings, browser settings or through Twitch's API).

My Internet connection is more than capable of downloading 10x the playback rate and I would like to increase the buffer size.

Comment: What would be your reason for increasing it? As it is a live broadcasting platform it doesn't sound like it would be useful, especially with a stable connection. I'd assume it's depending on the twitch settings rather than your browsers.

Comment: This is not possible sinds the buffersize is the delay the broadcaster has setup. Buffersize cant be increased and is around 30-60 seconds.

Comment: @Seth My first reason would be for when your internet connection briefly cuts out, I would want a large enough buffer to cover that period.

Comment: @DylanRz pretty sure that's not correct as if I view the same video on different devices connections you can get a different buffer size.  Also you can see from my screen shot the buffer size is less than 30s, Also when watching VODs (which I am) broadcaster delay has no relevance.

Comment: @unknownSPY When you watch a VOD you download directy from the twitch servers. When you watch a stream you download encoded data from the streamer. Buffersize can also be less then 30 seconds it depends on the distance you have to where the streamer is streaming from. When a streamer streams they always pick a location on where encoded data will get send to.

Comment: @DylanRz Sorry, but I don't think your last comment makes sense. for a start you are always downloading directly from twitch servers, there is no P2P. and Buffer size is more dependant on connection speed rather than distance.

Answer (score 2):

No. Twitch does not offer user configurable buffer size.

Comment: @Ramhound Why is this not an answer? The question asks "I was wondering whether buffer size was in any way configurable" - No is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill - You are right